# How can I count these words, using script in google sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, formula, counting

I'd like to count an occurrence number of one word in a string, but Google Sheets is giving me an error, that it can't deal with the expression:

```
finalScores.push(preOutputTxt.match(nameArr[x])).length);
```

because there is null somewhere. How can I fix this? 
Full code:

```
/**
*   
*   
* 
* @customFunction
*/

function scoreCounting(scores, names){
  //---variables---//
  var scoresArr = [];
  var preOutputTxt = "";
  var finalScores = [];
  var nameArr = [];
  //---------------//


  //---creating an array from names and scores (scores are in string type)---//
  for(var w = 0; w < scores.length; w ++){
    scoresArr.push(scores[w]);
  }
  for(var z = 0; z < names.length; z++){
    nameArr.push(names[z]);
  }
  //---------------------------------------//


  //---make one big string with names---//
  for(var y = 0; y < scoresArr.length; y++){
   preOutputTxt += scoresArr[y];
  }
  //----------------------------------------------//


  //---counting how many times score (a name) occur, basing on name given by nameArr[]---//
  for(var x = 0; x < nameArr.length; x++){ 
    finalScores.push(preOutputTxt.match(nameArr[x])).length); 
  }

  return finalScores;
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please share a copy of your spreadsheet, excluding private or confidential data. Would you also please edit your question to include the **exact** error message that you are getting - "_google sheets are giving me an error, that he cant deal with expression:... because there is null somewhere" tells us nothing about the nature of the error.

Answer (score 0):

As Tedinoz mentioned, it would be easier to offer specific help if you could share a spreadsheet.

But in the meantime, here are two snippets help explain how to get the count of a word in a longer string.

Example 1: If you use `match()` with the name as the input, you will get just the first match.

[This is because the method expects a regular expression. And passing a string (or a variable set to a string) is similar to a regex with no modifier.]

```
function example1() {
  var preOutputTxt = 'abcabcabc';
  var name  = 'abc';
  var output = preOutputTxt.match(name);
  Logger.log('Output is %s. Length is %s.', output, output.length);
}

// Output is [abc]. Length is 1.0.
```

Example 2: But if you use a regular expression with a global modifier, you will get all the matches.

```
function example2() {
  var preOutputTxt = 'abcabcabc';
  var name  = 'abc';
  var re = new RegExp(name, 'g');
  Logger.log('Regular expression is %s', re);
  var output = preOutputTxt.match(re);
  Logger.log('Output is %s. Length is %s.', output, output.length);
}

// Regular expression is /abc/g
// Output is [abc, abc, abc]. Length is 3.0.
```